# Compare multiple values to multiple columns in database with PHP and MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am making a PHP script which accepts five values from the user, say `$var1`, `$var2`, `$var3`, `$var4`, `$var5`. All of these will be stored as strings.

Now suppose that in my MySQL database I have a primary key and 5 columns, which also stores strings (named as `column1`, `column2` and so on).

So the question is, considering that I have connected PHP script to database and all other required things are done, what will be the most efficient query or way to achieve this task:

Compare the value of each variables to each of the columns in the table. Thus in total in worst case it'll do 5x5 i.e. 25 comparisons.

Is there any query like this:

```
select * from table_name
where (var1,var2,var3,var4,var5) in (column1,column2,column3,column4,column5)
```

If not what else can be the most time efficient way to achieve this?
The query must return the row in which *any* of the `$var` matches *any* of the `column`.

Comment: It's unclear to me whether you are trying to select the rows where column1=$var1 AND column2=$var2 etc., or whether you want all rows where column1=$var1 OR column2=$var2 etc...?

Comment: To me, it seems OP wants every row that has a match between $var* and column*, even if it's a single one.

Comment: @Kenney: looks like OP wants to find which column var1 is in (if any), which column var2 is in (if any), etc... basically an array intersection of the var/column values.

Comment: Could you be a bit clear on exactly what you want here? Does every variable have to correspond to a column? Does every column have to correspond to a variable? (Those two are different questions.)

Comment: This kind of problem is symptomatic of poor (i.e. denormalised) design

Comment: OP edited the question. It's what I've said.

Comment: Your syntax would compare ordered pairs, so only match `var1`=`column1` and `var2`=`column2` and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name
WHERE ? IN (column1,column2,column3,column4,column5)
OR    ? IN (column1,column2,column3,column4,column5)
OR    ? IN (column1,column2,column3,column4,column5)
OR    ? IN (column1,column2,column3,column4,column5)
OR    ? IN (column1,column2,column3,column4,column5)
```

and in your PHP you'd do this:

```
$sth = $pdo->prepare( "the query above" );
$sth->execute( array( $var1, $var2, $var3, $var4, $var5 ) );
```

(assuming you use PDO).

Comment: What if say `$var1 = $var2`, but `column1 != column2`?

Comment: @Anders As long as `$var1` or `$var2` is equal to `column1` or `colum2` (etc) it will match; OP's question: _Compare value of each variables to each of the column in the table in database._ (as clarified by @Alan and @Marc)

Comment: I don't get the whole `OR ? IN` repeating five times, can you explain the logic to me please?

Comment: The `?` is an SQL query parameter; so the five `?` correspond to `$var1, $var2, $var3, $var4, $var5`. So: `WHERE "$var1" IN (...) OR "$var2" IN (...)` etc..

Comment: I know what `?` stands for in PDO prepared statements, what I do not know is what **that one** prep stmt will generate. Seems like five lines of the same condition.

Comment: Shouldn't all variables correspond to one column? So that should be `AND` instead of `OR`? Or am I misunderstanding the question?

Comment: @Anders you misunderstood, indeed. OP seems to want any match at any pair degree

Comment: @AlanMachado Partly; the right hand side of the condition (after `IN`) is the same, but the `?` is (or can be) different each time.

Comment: @Kenney so `execute` will change each `?` for each array member, is that it?

Comment: @AlanMachado Yes that's it; it's a bit like `printf(" ..WHERE %s IN (..) OR %s IN ()", $var1, $var2, ...)`

Comment: @Kenney I'm not very into sql queries, so see if I'm right: is it possible to write it as `SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE ????? IN (column1,column2,column3,column4,column5);` ? Or even something like `WHERE ? OR ? OR ? OR ? OR ? IN...`? The way it is, seems like a slap in the DRY concept's face.

Comment: @AlanMachado No, you'd get a syntax error. Asssuming `$var1="A"` and `$var2="B"` etc, the query will be like `WHERE 'A''B''C''D''E' IN (...` - if it even gets that far. It treats the `?` as an operand, and you cannot have 2 (or more) operands directly following each other. You could do `..WHERE column1 IN (?,?,?,?,?) OR column2 IN (...` but that would require 25 query parameters.